# Spark: what could cause a worker to run indefinitevely without doing anything

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe

I've finished my program who seems to work ok, but when I launch it for good with a few Gb, I often meet a problem after a while.

When I go on on myhost:7080, I can see the applications running and being completed, but suddenly it stops going forward and one of the application remains on running. There s' nothing else happening.

This could happen at any stage. Sometimes it takes 5 minutes, sometimes 50 minutes or sometimes it just finishes noramlly after 70 minutes.

Usually, when it happens my putty session display a pop up telling there s an error with the connection has and become inactive.

Any idea of where the problem could come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Spark job or are you running spark as an execution engine for Hive? I have faced the same problem where spark jobs are hung/taking long time when it is used as an execution engine for hive. Can you please share more details?

Also what is your cluster configuration?